# GLB texture not applying in sceneform

Tags: android, 3d, arcore, sceneform

I'm using sceneform 1.17.1 in a android app and and downloading the glb to show it.
My issue is that I have two 3D models and in one, the image texture applies fine. In the other one, the image texture does not apply.

Using khronos gltf validator they look similar. This is the one that works fine:

```
{
    "uri": "AviatorApp_98.glb",
    "mimeType": "model/gltf-binary",
    "validatorVersion": "2.0.0-dev.3.2",
    "validatedAt": "2020-08-24T12:53:37.209Z",
    "issues": {
        "numErrors": 0,
        "numWarnings": 0,
        "numInfos": 0,
        "numHints": 0,
        "messages": [],
        "truncated": false
    },
    "info": {
        "version": "2.0",
        "generator": "Gestaltor 2020.2.1 Alpha 'Zuckerwatte' (CI-38fb8ee1*)",
        "resources": [
            {
                "pointer": "/buffers/0",
                "mimeType": "application/gltf-buffer",
                "storage": "glb",
                "byteLength": 1501852
            },
            {
                "pointer": "/images/0",
                "mimeType": "image/jpeg",
                "storage": "buffer-view",
                "image": {
                    "width": 1024,
                    "height": 1024,
                    "format": "rgb",
                    "bits": 8
                }
            },
            {
                "pointer": "/images/1",
                "mimeType": "image/png",
                "storage": "buffer-view",
                "image": {
                    "width": 1024,
                    "height": 1024,
                    "format": "rgba",
                    "primaries": "srgb",
                    "transfer": "srgb",
                    "bits": 8
                }
            }
        ],
        "animationCount": 0,
        "materialCount": 3,
        "hasMorphTargets": false,
        "hasSkins": false,
        "hasTextures": true,
        "hasDefaultScene": true,
        "drawCallCount": 3,
        "totalVertexCount": 15848,
        "totalTriangleCount": 28336,
        "maxUVs": 1,
        "maxInfluences": 0,
        "maxAttributes": 4
    }
}
```

How it looks:
[image: virtual sunglasses in face]

And this is the one that does not load the texture:

```
{
    "uri": "ChromanceApp_98_2.glb",
    "mimeType": "model/gltf-binary",
    "validatorVersion": "2.0.0-dev.3.2",
    "validatedAt": "2020-08-24T12:56:29.902Z",
    "issues": {
        "numErrors": 0,
        "numWarnings": 0,
        "numInfos": 0,
        "numHints": 0,
        "messages": [],
        "truncated": false
    },
    "info": {
        "version": "2.0",
        "generator": "Gestaltor 2020.2.1 Alpha 'Zuckerwatte' (CI-38fb8ee1*)",
        "resources": [
            {
                "pointer": "/buffers/0",
                "mimeType": "application/gltf-buffer",
                "storage": "glb",
                "byteLength": 3235956
            },
            {
                "pointer": "/images/0",
                "mimeType": "image/jpeg",
                "storage": "buffer-view",
                "image": {
                    "width": 1024,
                    "height": 1024,
                    "format": "rgb",
                    "bits": 8
                }
            },
            {
                "pointer": "/images/1",
                "mimeType": "image/png",
                "storage": "buffer-view",
                "image": {
                    "width": 1024,
                    "height": 1024,
                    "format": "rgba",
                    "primaries": "srgb",
                    "transfer": "srgb",
                    "bits": 8
                }
            }
        ],
        "animationCount": 0,
        "materialCount": 3,
        "hasMorphTargets": false,
        "hasSkins": false,
        "hasTextures": true,
        "hasDefaultScene": true,
        "drawCallCount": 3,
        "totalVertexCount": 51070,
        "totalTriangleCount": 38324,
        "maxUVs": 1,
        "maxInfluences": 0,
        "maxAttributes": 4
    }
}
```

How this looks:
[image: virtual sunglasses without texture]

I don't get any errors in the app. How can I show the my 3D model with the texture?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the way the 3D was being exported. It was being exported as a FBX and then converted to GLB. When it was change to be exported as an OBJ with a different scale and then converted to GLB. It worked fine.